# What is a good Ruby on Rails forum that can easily integrated to an existing application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid, haml, forum

What is a good, open source RoR 3 forum that can easily integrated to an existing application?

**Optional features:**

- OpenID support
- Haml/SCSS templates
- Support for smilies, YouTube, images, etc
- I'm probably going to change it alot, and I'm still pretty weak in Ruby, so clean, commented code with good practices would be great.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails community has never been focused on developing Ruby/Rails forums, conversely to other languages such as PHP. The evidence of that is a [really old news](http://www.rubyinside.com/beast-an-open-source-rails-forum-in-500-lines-of-code-191.html) talking about one of the forums prototype ever produces in Rails.

You can still found traces of Beast [somewhere](http://github.com/courtenay/altered_beast), but the real answer is that there's no interesting open source Rails forum available from the time being.

Comment: You have several alternatives: 1. install a forum developed with a different language and use API to talk with it from your Rails app 2. develop your own solution 3. use a third party service

Comment: I think I will develop my own solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Recently I was searching for similar functionality and came across [discourse](https://github.com/discourse/discourse). You should definitely check it out.

```
Discourse is the 100% open source, next-generation discussion platform built 
for the next decade of the Internet.

Whenever you need ...

a mailing list
a forum to discuss something
a chat room where you can type paragraphs

... consider Discourse.
```

Its developed by Jeff Atwood and [team](http://blog.discourse.org/2013/02/the-discourse-team/)

Comment: The best part is, it's being actively developed (& maintained) and you can actually contribute to it if you find that it's lacking something!

Comment: Except that it's being designed to be a stand alone, when what we really want is an engine we can make use of in our own sites.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on http://github.com/radar/rboard  the most powerful and poplar in Rails world at the moment

Comment: It is now superseded by [forem](https://github.com/radar/forem), also from radar.

Answer (score 1):

[Thredded](https://thredded.org/) does all of this and more.

Because Thredded is a Rails engine, it is very easy to integrate it into an existing app.

[image: Thredded demo screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [Forulio](http://forulio.com/) ? Seems like you can build on it . Looks decent to start with.