# What is the best Ruby on Rails forum based?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forum, communityengine

I have been looking for forums developed in Ruby on Rails and I found some solutions like *threaded*, *sugar*, *forum monster* and *forem*.

Could do you suggest me one of them and pros/cons?

I'm a RoR newbie and I'm looking for a solution that can allow me create a "community" around this forum and learn more RoR during the trip.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857464/what-is-a-good-ruby-on-rails-forum-that-can-easily-integrated-to-an-existing-app

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest you. This forum software.

https://github.com/discourse/discourse

This looks awesome.

Comment: It looks awesome but have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Yes @HassanAzimi thats why I m suggesting.